# Not able to click on option available only on mousehover

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on an application which has a *Logout* option on top left. The button is in a way that it consisits of 2 parts, Parent button -

```
<span id="buttonOptions" class="yui-button yui-split-button">
```

whose class is dynamic in a way that there are 2 options i.e. a Username(on right side)

```
<span id="buttonOptions" class="yui-button yui-split-button yui-button-hover
   yui-split-bitton-hover">
```

and an arrow(on left side) for more options,

```
<span id="buttonOptions" class="yui-button yui-split-button yui-button-hover
   yui-split-bitton-hover yui-split-bitton-hoveroptions">
```

both having a dynamic class which appears on mousehover on certain part of span. How do I click Option arrow i.e.

```
<span id="buttonOptions" class="yui-button yui-split-button yui-button-hover
   yui-split-bitton-hover yui-split-bitton-hoveroptions">
```

Comment: could you please share the code you have written so that we can understand more?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. A screenshot of the different states of the button would probably help our understanding also.

Comment: Have you tried using `Actions` to hover the button and then click on the arrow?